# creating two-way communication fifo

Tags: c, fifo

I can create a FIFO for one-way communication. But how would I go for two-way communication? I can create a C file which can act as the sender and open another terminal which acts as receiver. But how would I establish the two-way communication? Thanks!

Comment: You create *two* FIFOs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that's what we're tasked to do. But the the two fifos should be in one file only. How would I create a pair of FIFOS?

Comment: You can't use a single file for two FIFO's, it's just not possible. At least not unless you implement *your own* FIFO, but that's going to be **very** hard.

Comment: Can I use fork() to send and receive simultaneously?

Comment: No, a pipe (which a FIFO is) is a one-way-only communication device. If you want bidirectional communication, you always needs two, no matter how many processes or threads you have.

Comment: Well, technically, you *could* achieve this with a single pipe if, every time you need to switch directions in your protocol, both ends close and re-open the single pipe with the opposite direction specified. But that's ugly, hackish, fragile, and unnecessarily complex, and I should probably be shot for even suggesting it... Better to just create a second pipe, or a socketpair...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Try a socket. Consider reading the manual for the socketpair function.